# Why won't Python regex work on a formatted string of HTML?

Tags: python, regex

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

soup = urllib.urlopen("http://atlanta.craigslist.org/cto/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup)
souped = soup.p
print souped
m = re.search("\\$.",souped)
print m.group(0)
```

I can download and print out the html just fine, but it always breaks when I add the last two lines.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 655, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "C:\Users\Zack\Documents\Scripto.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Thanks lots!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want `re.search("\\$.", str(souped))`.

Comment: To expand on this, BeautifulSoup objects have a `__str__()` method to convert them to strings, so they can be printed nicely (because `print` will do that automatically), but they are not actually strings, and `re.search()` wants a string. Hence you must explicitly convert the HTML to a string so you can search it.

Comment: +1, but I would use unicode(), not str, if possible. And add the re.U flag.

Answer (score 1):

Because `souped` is an object and `print`ing it converts it to text. But if you want to use it in another context (like you do, as text), you should convert it first like `str(souped)` or `unicode(souped)` if it's a unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a regex as search criteria to [`.find()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#text):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen # from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> import re
>>> page = urlopen("http://atlanta.craigslist.org/cto/")
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
>>> soup.find('p', text=re.compile(r"\$."))
' -\n\t\t\t $7500'
```

`soup.p` returns a `Tag` object. You could use [`str()` or `unicode()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#non-pretty-printing)  to convert it to string:

```
>>> p = soup.p
>>> str(p)
'<p class="row">\n<span class="ih" id="images:5Nb5I85J83N73p33H6
c2pd3447d5bff6d1757.jpg">\xa0</span>\n<a href="http://atlanta.cr
aigslist.org/nat/cto/2870295634.html">2000 Lexus RX 300</a> -\n\
t\t\t $7500<font size="-1"> (Buford)</font> <span class="p"> pic
\xa0img</span><br class="c" />\n</p>'
>>> re.search(r"\$.", str(p)).group(0)
'$7'
```